# How to make smm panels bots?

Tags: bots

I would like to know the working of smm panels like **worldofsmm** , justanotherpanel.com
these websites giving or generating followers,likes  & Views on demand. Many profile seems genuine. how their scripts works ? all of these websites are just resellers [worldofsmm](https://worldofsmm.com)

please help me with working of bots ?
thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.